# Magento 1.8 remove default google font from head

Tags: fonts

I searched Stackexchange but my question is different from others. I saw a similar question with Magento 1.9 but that solution does not work on 1.8. So therefor I ask my question.

I noticed that the browsers block this content from my https Magento:

```
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&subset=latin' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
```

I did not put this line there, so I guess it is Magento default / pre-installed. I've been searching on the server but cannot find the file that is responsible for putting that line in the head.

Can anyone tell me where I can find the responsible file? So that, hopefully, I can easily remove this line and make my website 100% https secure.

Thank you in advance. John

Answer (score 0):

It's set in `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml`. You'll notice following line:

```
<action method="addLinkRel"><rel>stylesheet</rel><href>//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,500,700,600</href></action>
```

You can easily remove it by adding following lines in your local.xml:

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="removeItem"><type>link_rel</type><name>//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&subset=latin</name></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

If that method is not helping you, I guess that you have purchased 3rd party theme which is injecting that for you. In that case, you'll have to search through your code for "Raleway" string, and then we can work further how to properly remove it.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I don't have the folder /rwd/. I do see some page.xml files, but they don't have the string. In my template folder, there is no page.xml file.

Comment: Try to search all files in your `app/` directory for "Raleway" string, and let me know if you've found it somewhere.

Comment: Is there a way to search automatically through the files for that string? Or do I have to open each file manually and do a manual search?

Comment: You can do it with any IDE, like PhpStorm, Eclipse, even Sublime, Atom... If you want to do it from the command line, just type `grep -r "Railway" app/`.

Comment: Thanks. I found 1 hit in this file: 

code/local/MagenThemes/MTTheme/Model/System/Config/Source/Design/Font/Family/Google.php
`code`<?php class MagenThemes_MTTheme_Model_System_Config_Source_Design_Font_Family_Google { public function toOptionArray() { $gfont = 'Abel,Abril,etc...,Raleway,Rammetto One,etc...';   $fontarray = explode(',',$gfont);  $options = array();   $options[] = array(  'value' => '', 'label' => '--Selec --', ); foreach($fontarray as $font){ $options[] = array(
       'value' => $font,    'label' => $font,
      );
        } 
        return $options;
    }
}
`code`

Comment: That hit which you've found says that there is configuration option in Magento Admin (probably somewhere in System -> Configuration -> MagenThemes or something related to that company) where you can adjust font.

Comment: There is only one font option called "Basic Font size" and "Headings Family" and that is set to "Arial. I cán choose for Google Fonts there, but I haven't. There is no option to uncheck Google Fonts, just the option to choose for Arial or others.

Comment: It's hidden somewhere in your code, but unfortunately, no one can help you more without access to it.

Comment: Come on, we can do it together :-)  I also searched for string "googleapis" and got 1 hit in file: design/frontend/mtbelano/default/template/page/html/head.phtml.  The source is: <link href                                                    ='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=<?php echo str_replace(' ', '+', $theme->get                                                    ThemeDesignCfg('font/primary_font_family')); echo $charSubset; ?>' rel='styleshe                                                    et' type='text/css' />   Isn't that exactly the string that is in the head of the page?

Comment: Try to remove that part of code, clear the cache, and check how it behaves. That's what I would do :)